# There seems to be some IE incompatible javascript here. Are there any browser compatibility experts around?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

This javascript works fine in FF v3.5.3, but not in IE 6.02. Can someone who is experienced in IE JS compatiblity please review this code for possible incompatibilities? I didn't include the code for all the functions being called because that would make my code sample huge, but I have tested the functions before in IE and they worked. I think the problem is in how I'm iterating over the JSON data. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jsInit("http://railsacrosseurope.com/public",
       "http://railsacrosseurope.com",
       "http://apps.facebook.com/rails_across_europe",
       "85572859349");
var routeData = [{"id":1,"c1_id":43,"c2_id":56,"cost":20,"c1_x":658,"c1_y":68,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":2,"c1_id":27,"c2_id":56,"cost":25,"c1_x":571,"c1_y":10,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":3,"c1_id":39,"c2_id":56,"cost":20,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":53,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":4,"c1_id":56,"c2_id":8,"cost":18,"c1_x":568,"c1_y":149,"c2_x":495,"c2_y":202,"owned":false},{"id":5,"c1_id":56,"c2_id":49,"cost":14,"c1_x":568,"c1_y":149,"c2_x":605,"c2_y":217,"owned":false},{"id":6,"c1_id":49,"c2_id":4,"cost":14,"c1_x":605,"c1_y":217,"c2_x":572,"c2_y":282,"owned":false},{"id":7,"c1_id":8,"c2_id":10,"cost":11,"c1_x":495,"c1_y":202,"c2_x":448,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":8,"c1_id":4,"c2_id":48,"cost":10,"c1_x":572,"c1_y":282,"c2_x":504,"c2_y":293,"owned":false},{"id":9,"c1_id":48,"c2_id":10,"cost":12,"c1_x":504,"c1_y":293,"c2_x":448,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":10,"c1_id":10,"c2_id":31,"cost":17,"c1_x":448,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":450,"c2_y":370,"owned":false},{"id":11,"c1_id":48,"c2_id":33,"cost":16,"c1_x":504,"c1_y":293,"c2_x":530,"c2_y":373,"owned":false},{"id":12,"c1_id":10,"c2_id":35,"cost":14,"c1_x":448,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":372,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":13,"c1_id":33,"c2_id":47,"cost":17,"c1_x":530,"c1_y":373,"c2_x":479,"c2_y":431,"owned":false},{"id":14,"c1_id":33,"c2_id":31,"cost":15,"c1_x":530,"c1_y":373,"c2_x":450,"c2_y":370,"owned":false},{"id":15,"c1_id":47,"c2_id":57,"cost":9,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":431,"c2_x":479,"c2_y":466,"owned":false},{"id":16,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":60,"cost":12,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":484,"c2_y":527,"owned":false},{"id":17,"c1_id":60,"c2_id":17,"cost":12,"c1_x":484,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":521,"c2_y":511,"owned":false},{"id":18,"c1_id":17,"c2_id":58,"cost":13,"c1_x":521,"c1_y":511,"c2_x":598,"c2_y":527,"owned":false},{"id":19,"c1_id":58,"c2_id":36,"cost":10,"c1_x":598,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":650,"c2_y":584,"owned":false},{"id":20,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":7,"cost":16,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":432,"owned":false},{"id":21,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":54,"cost":14,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":462,"owned":false},{"id":22,"c1_id":31,"c2_id":59,"cost":16,"c1_x":450,"c1_y":370,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":344,"owned":false},{"id":23,"c1_id":35,"c2_id":59,"cost":14,"c1_x":372,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":344,"owned":false},{"id":24,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":29,"cost":19,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":260,"c2_y":314,"owned":false},{"id":25,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":12,"cost":12,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":299,"c2_y":395,"owned":false},{"id":26,"c1_id":12,"c2_id":2,"cost":6,"c1_x":299,"c1_y":395,"c2_x":290,"c2_y":400,"owned":false},{"id":27,"c1_id":2,"c2_id":22,"cost":10,"c1_x":290,"c1_y":400,"c2_x":255,"c2_y":412,"owned":false},{"id":28,"c1_id":22,"c2_id":29,"cost":16,"c1_x":255,"c1_y":412,"c2_x":260,"c2_y":314,"owned":false},{"id":29,"c1_id":29,"c2_id":14,"cost":14,"c1_x":260,"c1_y":314,"c2_x":232,"c2_y":257,"owned":false},{"id":30,"c1_id":29,"c2_id":9,"cost":10,"c1_x":260,"c1_y":314,"c2_x":209,"c2_y":300,"owned":false},{"id":31,"c1_id":9,"c2_id":32,"cost":8,"c1_x":209,"c1_y":300,"c2_x":192,"c2_y":308,"owned":false},{"id":32,"c1_id":32,"c2_id":16,"cost":12,"c1_x":192,"c1_y":308,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":225,"owned":false},{"id":33,"c1_id":16,"c2_id":15,"cost":10,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":225,"c2_x":195,"c2_y":166,"owned":false},{"id":34,"c1_id":32,"c2_id":37,"cost":11,"c1_x":192,"c1_y":308,"c2_x":155,"c2_y":315,"owned":true},{"id":35,"c1_id":37,"c2_id":19,"cost":9,"c1_x":155,"c1_y":315,"c2_x":101,"c2_y":285,"owned":true},{"id":36,"c1_id":19,"c2_id":1,"cost":12,"c1_x":101,"c1_y":285,"c2_x":70,"c2_y":330,"owned":true},{"id":37,"c1_id":19,"c2_id":5,"cost":12,"c1_x":101,"c1_y":285,"c2_x":131,"c2_y":243,"owned":false},{"id":38,"c1_id":22,"c2_id":41,"cost":12,"c1_x":255,"c1_y":412,"c2_x":304,"c2_y":461,"owned":true},{"id":39,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":18,"cost":12,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":499,"owned":true},{"id":40,"c1_id":18,"c2_id":45,"cost":8,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":499,"c2_x":370,"c2_y":504,"owned":false},{"id":41,"c1_id":45,"c2_id":54,"cost":13,"c1_x":370,"c1_y":504,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":462,"owned":false},{"id":42,"c1_id":54,"c2_id":34,"cost":14,"c1_x":430,"c1_y":462,"c2_x":400,"c2_y":532,"owned":false},{"id":43,"c1_id":34,"c2_id":51,"cost":19,"c1_x":400,"c1_y":532,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":44,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":26,"cost":16,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":300,"c2_y":554,"owned":true},{"id":45,"c1_id":26,"c2_id":55,"cost":11,"c1_x":300,"c1_y":554,"c2_x":270,"c2_y":573,"owned":false},{"id":46,"c1_id":26,"c2_id":40,"cost":12,"c1_x":300,"c1_y":554,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":585,"owned":false},{"id":47,"c1_id":40,"c2_id":51,"cost":13,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":585,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":48,"c1_id":60,"c2_id":53,"cost":17,"c1_x":484,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":470,"c2_y":610,"owned":false},{"id":49,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":51,"cost":11,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":50,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":42,"cost":13,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":540,"c2_y":659,"owned":false},{"id":51,"c1_id":42,"c2_id":6,"cost":10,"c1_x":540,"c1_y":659,"c2_x":510,"c2_y":705,"owned":false},{"id":52,"c1_id":6,"c2_id":53,"cost":16,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":705,"c2_x":470,"c2_y":610,"owned":true},{"id":53,"c1_id":6,"c2_id":13,"cost":13,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":705,"c2_x":433,"c2_y":673,"owned":false},{"id":54,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":13,"cost":15,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":433,"c2_y":673,"owned":false},{"id":55,"c1_id":13,"c2_id":51,"cost":15,"c1_x":433,"c1_y":673,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":56,"c1_id":51,"c2_id":25,"cost":16,"c1_x":408,"c1_y":623,"c2_x":338,"c2_y":693,"owned":false},{"id":57,"c1_id":25,"c2_id":28,"cost":11,"c1_x":338,"c1_y":693,"c2_x":298,"c2_y":675,"owned":false},{"id":58,"c1_id":28,"c2_id":50,"cost":8,"c1_x":298,"c1_y":675,"c2_x":282,"c2_y":710,"owned":false},{"id":59,"c1_id":50,"c2_id":23,"cost":12,"c1_x":282,"c1_y":710,"c2_x":210,"c2_y":699,"owned":false},{"id":60,"c1_id":40,"c2_id":52,"cost":11,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":585,"c2_x":314,"c2_y":639,"owned":false},{"id":61,"c1_id":52,"c2_id":28,"cost":10,"c1_x":314,"c1_y":639,"c2_x":298,"c2_y":675,"owned":false},{"id":62,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":11,"cost":12,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":232,"c2_y":490,"owned":true},{"id":63,"c1_id":11,"c2_id":21,"cost":9,"c1_x":232,"c1_y":490,"c2_x":230,"c2_y":513,"owned":true},{"id":64,"c1_id":55,"c2_id":21,"cost":15,"c1_x":270,"c1_y":573,"c2_x":230,"c2_y":513,"owned":true},{"id":65,"c1_id":55,"c2_id":46,"cost":9,"c1_x":270,"c1_y":573,"c2_x":240,"c2_y":596,"owned":false},{"id":66,"c1_id":46,"c2_id":24,"cost":19,"c1_x":240,"c1_y":596,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":560,"owned":true},{"id":67,"c1_id":21,"c2_id":3,"cost":11,"c1_x":230,"c1_y":513,"c2_x":150,"c2_y":528,"owned":true},{"id":68,"c1_id":3,"c2_id":24,"cost":13,"c1_x":150,"c1_y":528,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":560,"owned":false},{"id":69,"c1_id":24,"c2_id":20,"cost":12,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":560,"c2_x":112,"c2_y":567,"owned":false},{"id":70,"c1_id":20,"c2_id":38,"cost":12,"c1_x":112,"c1_y":567,"c2_x":38,"c2_y":553,"owned":true},{"id":71,"c1_id":24,"c2_id":44,"cost":22,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":560,"c2_x":61,"c2_y":661,"owned":false},{"id":72,"c1_id":38,"c2_id":44,"cost":16,"c1_x":38,"c1_y":553,"c2_x":61,"c2_y":661,"owned":true},{"id":73,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":30,"cost":16,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":340,"c2_y":425,"owned":false},{"id":74,"c1_id":30,"c2_id":41,"cost":12,"c1_x":340,"c1_y":425,"c2_x":304,"c2_y":461,"owned":false},{"id":75,"c1_id":30,"c2_id":18,"cost":12,"c1_x":340,"c1_y":425,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":499,"owned":true}];
var trainData = [{"player_number":2,"id":2,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":2,"game_id":1,"player_id":0,"route_id":18,"origin_city_id":58,"dest_city_id":17,"track_unit":3,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[{"train_id":2,"goods_id":31,"name":"Furniture"},{"train_id":2,"goods_id":7,"name":"Chocolate"}]},{"player_number":3,"id":3,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":3,"game_id":1,"player_id":0,"route_id":30,"origin_city_id":9,"dest_city_id":29,"track_unit":2,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[{"train_id":3,"goods_id":19,"name":"Marble"}]},{"player_number":5,"id":4,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":4,"game_id":1,"player_id":0,"route_id":5,"origin_city_id":49,"dest_city_id":56,"track_unit":2,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[]},{"player_number":4,"id":5,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":5,"game_id":1,"player_id":0,"route_id":1,"origin_city_id":56,"dest_city_id":43,"track_unit":0,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ARRIVED","goods":[]},{"player_number":1,"id":15,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":1,"game_id":1,"player_id":1,"route_id":67,"origin_city_id":21,"dest_city_id":3,"track_unit":8,"direction":"+","line":"RED","status":"ARRIVED","goods":[{"train_id":15,"goods_id":29,"name":"Timber"},{"train_id":15,"goods_id":2,"name":"Ale"},{"train_id":15,"goods_id":38,"name":"Optical Instruments"}]}];
var routeCount = [routeData.length];
var train = [];
var trackColor = "#888";
for(var i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
  var trainCount = 0;
  train = [];
  routeCount[i] = [];
  routeCount[i].route_id = routeData[i].id;
  trackColor = routeData[i].owned ? "#555" : "#888";
  for(var j = 0; j < trainData.length; j++) {
    if(trainData[j].route_id == i) {
      train[trainCount] = trainData[j];
      trainCount++;
    }
  }
  drawTrack(routeData[i]["c1_y"],
                        routeData[i]["c1_x"],
                        routeData[i]["c2_y"],
                        routeData[i]["c2_x"],
                        trackColor,
                        train);
}
var cityGoods = [{"city_id":17,"city_name":"Florence","city_x":521,"city_y":511,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_marble.gif"],"goods_name":["Marble"]},{"city_id":19,"city_name":"Glasgow","city_x":101,"city_y":285,"goods_index":2,"goods_image":["goods_icon_computers.gif","goods_icon_wool.gif"],"goods_name":["Computers","Wool"]},{"city_id":30,"city_name":"Luxembourg","city_x":340,"city_y":425,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_computers.gif"],"goods_name":["Computers"]},{"city_id":32,"city_name":"Manchester","city_x":192,"city_y":308,"goods_index":2,"goods_image":["goods_icon_computers.gif","goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Computers","Autos"]},{"city_id":45,"city_name":"Stuttgart","city_x":370,"city_y":504,"goods_index":2,"goods_image":["goods_icon_computers.gif","goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Computers","Autos"]},{"city_id":52,"city_name":"Wroclaw","city_x":314,"city_y":639,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_computers.gif"],"goods_name":["Computers"]},{"city_id":13,"city_name":"Budapest","city_x":433,"city_y":673,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_aluminum.gif"],"goods_name":["Aluminum"]},{"city_id":11,"city_name":"Bremen","city_x":232,"city_y":490,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":14,"city_name":"Cardiff","city_x":232,"city_y":257,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":20,"city_name":"Goteburg","city_x":112,"city_y":567,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":34,"city_name":"Munich","city_x":400,"city_y":532,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":36,"city_name":"Naples","city_x":650,"city_y":584,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":47,"city_name":"Turin","city_x":479,"city_y":431,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_auto.gif"],"goods_name":["Autos"]},{"city_id":8,"city_name":"Bilbao","city_x":495,"city_y":202,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_wool.gif"],"goods_name":["Wool"]},{"city_id":15,"city_name":"Cork","city_x":195,"city_y":166,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_wool.gif"],"goods_name":["Wool"]},{"city_id":24,"city_name":"Copenhagen","city_x":170,"city_y":560,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_engines.gif"],"goods_name":["Engines"]},{"city_id":33,"city_name":"Marseille","city_x":530,"city_y":373,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_engines.gif"],"goods_name":["Engines"]},{"city_id":40,"city_name":"Prague","city_x":350,"city_y":585,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_engines.gif"],"goods_name":["Engines"]},{"city_id":4,"city_name":"Barcelona","city_x":572,"city_y":282,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_fruit.gif"],"goods_name":["Fruit"]},{"city_id":43,"city_name":"Seville","city_x":658,"city_y":68,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_fruit.gif"],"goods_name":["Fruit"]},{"city_id":49,"city_name":"Valencia","city_x":605,"city_y":217,"goods_index":2,"goods_image":["goods_icon_fruit.gif","goods_icon_silk.gif"],"goods_name":["Fruit","Silk"]},{"city_id":31,"city_name":"Lyon","city_x":450,"city_y":370,"goods_index":1,"goods_image":["goods_icon_silk.gif"],"goods_name":["Silk"]}];
  drawCityGoods(cityGoods);
var cities = [{"id":1,"name":"Aberdeen","x":70,"y":330,"image":""},{"id":2,"name":"Antwerpen","x":290,"y":400,"image":""},{"id":3,"name":"Arhus","x":150,"y":528,"image":""},{"id":4,"name":"Barcelona","x":572,"y":282,"image":""},{"id":5,"name":"Belfast","x":131,"y":243,"image":""},{"id":6,"name":"Belgrade","x":510,"y":705,"image":""},{"id":7,"name":"Bern","x":430,"y":432,"image":""},{"id":8,"name":"Bilbao","x":495,"y":202,"image":""},{"id":9,"name":"Birmingham","x":209,"y":300,"image":""},{"id":10,"name":"Bordeaux","x":448,"y":250,"image":""},{"id":11,"name":"Bremen","x":232,"y":490,"image":""},{"id":12,"name":"Brussels","x":299,"y":395,"image":""},{"id":13,"name":"Budapest","x":433,"y":673,"image":""},{"id":14,"name":"Cardiff","x":232,"y":257,"image":""},{"id":15,"name":"Cork","x":195,"y":166,"image":""},{"id":16,"name":"Dublin","x":170,"y":225,"image":""},{"id":17,"name":"Florence","x":521,"y":511,"image":""},{"id":18,"name":"Frankfurt","x":350,"y":499,"image":""},{"id":19,"name":"Glasgow","x":101,"y":285,"image":""},{"id":20,"name":"Goteburg","x":112,"y":567,"image":""},{"id":21,"name":"Hamburg","x":230,"y":513,"image":""},{"id":22,"name":"Holland","x":255,"y":412,"image":""},{"id":23,"name":"Kalningrad","x":210,"y":699,"image":""},{"id":24,"name":"Copenhagen","x":170,"y":560,"image":""},{"id":25,"name":"Krakow","x":338,"y":693,"image":""},{"id":26,"name":"Leipzig","x":300,"y":554,"image":""},{"id":27,"name":"Lisbon","x":571,"y":10,"image":""},{"id":28,"name":"Lodz","x":298,"y":675,"image":""},{"id":29,"name":"London","x":260,"y":314,"image":""},{"id":30,"name":"Luxembourg","x":340,"y":425,"image":""},{"id":31,"name":"Lyon","x":450,"y":370,"image":""},{"id":32,"name":"Manchester","x":192,"y":308,"image":""},{"id":33,"name":"Marseille","x":530,"y":373,"image":""},{"id":34,"name":"Munich","x":400,"y":532,"image":""},{"id":35,"name":"Nantes","x":372,"y":250,"image":""},{"id":36,"name":"Naples","x":650,"y":584,"image":""},{"id":37,"name":"Newcastle","x":155,"y":315,"image":""},{"id":38,"name":"Oslo","x":38,"y":553,"image":""},{"id":39,"name":"Porto","x":510,"y":53,"image":""},{"id":40,"name":"Prague","x":350,"y":585,"image":""},{"id":41,"name":"Ruhr","x":304,"y":461,"image":""},{"id":42,"name":"Sarajevo","x":540,"y":659,"image":""},{"id":43,"name":"Seville","x":658,"y":68,"image":""},{"id":44,"name":"Stockholm","x":61,"y":661,"image":""},{"id":45,"name":"Stuttgart","x":370,"y":504,"image":""},{"id":46,"name":"Szczecin","x":240,"y":596,"image":""},{"id":47,"name":"Turin","x":479,"y":431,"image":""},{"id":48,"name":"Toulouse","x":504,"y":293,"image":""},{"id":49,"name":"Valencia","x":605,"y":217,"image":""},{"id":50,"name":"Warsaw","x":282,"y":710,"image":""},{"id":51,"name":"Vienna","x":408,"y":623,"image":""},{"id":52,"name":"Wroclaw","x":314,"y":639,"image":""},{"id":53,"name":"Zagreb","x":470,"y":610,"image":""},{"id":54,"name":"Zurich","x":430,"y":462,"image":""},{"id":55,"name":"Berlin","x":270,"y":573,"image":""},{"id":56,"name":"Madrid","x":568,"y":149,"image":""},{"id":57,"name":"Milan","x":479,"y":466,"image":""},{"id":58,"name":"Rome","x":598,"y":527,"image":""},{"id":59,"name":"Paris","x":350,"y":344,"image":""},{"id":60,"name":"Venice","x":484,"y":527,"image":""}];
for(key in cities) {
  var cityLink = "http://apps.facebook.com/rails_across_europe/turn/start_set_city?city_id="+cities[key]["id"];
  cities[key]["city_id"] = cities[key]["id"];
  cities[key]["city_name"] = cities[key]["name"];
  cities[key]["city_x"] = cities[key]["x"];
  cities[key]["city_y"] = cities[key]["y"];
  cities[key]["city_link"] = cityLink;
}  drawCities(cities);
  param = { "routes": [{ "id": 1, "count": 9},{ "id": 2, "count": 14},{ "id": 3, "count": 10},{ "id": 4, "count": 8},{ "id": 5, "count": 7},{ "id": 6, "count": 7},{ "id": 7, "count": 5},{ "id": 8, "count": 7},{ "id": 9, "count": 6},{ "id": 10, "count": 12},{ "id": 11, "count": 8},{ "id": 12, "count": 8},{ "id": 13, "count": 6},{ "id": 14, "count": 8},{ "id": 15, "count": 4},{ "id": 16, "count": 7},{ "id": 17, "count": 4},{ "id": 18, "count": 8},{ "id": 19, "count": 6},{ "id": 20, "count": 5},{ "id": 21, "count": 5},{ "id": 22, "count": 10},{ "id": 23, "count": 10},{ "id": 24, "count": 9},{ "id": 25, "count": 6},{ "id": 26, "count": 1},{ "id": 27, "count": 4},{ "id": 28, "count": 10},{ "id": 29, "count": 6},{ "id": 30, "count": 6},{ "id": 31, "count": 2},{ "id": 32, "count": 9},{ "id": 33, "count": 6},{ "id": 34, "count": 4},{ "id": 35, "count": 6},{ "id": 36, "count": 5},{ "id": 37, "count": 5},{ "id": 38, "count": 5},{ "id": 39, "count": 5},{ "id": 40, "count": 2},{ "id": 41, "count": 6},{ "id": 42, "count": 7},{ "id": 43, "count": 10},{ "id": 44, "count": 10},{ "id": 45, "count": 3},{ "id": 46, "count": 5},{ "id": 47, "count": 6},{ "id": 48, "count": 9},{ "id": 49, "count": 7},{ "id": 50, "count": 7},{ "id": 51, "count": 5},{ "id": 52, "count": 10},{ "id": 53, "count": 8},{ "id": 54, "count": 7},{ "id": 55, "count": 5},{ "id": 56, "count": 7},{ "id": 57, "count": 4},{ "id": 58, "count": 4},{ "id": 59, "count": 8},{ "id": 60, "count": 6},{ "id": 61, "count": 4},{ "id": 62, "count": 8},{ "id": 63, "count": 3},{ "id": 64, "count": 6},{ "id": 65, "count": 3},{ "id": 66, "count": 7},{ "id": 67, "count": 8},{ "id": 68, "count": 4},{ "id": 69, "count": 6},{ "id": 70, "count": 8},{ "id": 71, "count": 11},{ "id": 72, "count": 11},{ "id": 73, "count": 9},{ "id": 74, "count": 4},{ "id": 75, "count": 8}] };
  var ajax = new Ajax();
  ajax.post("http://railsacrosseurope.com/turn/update_track", param);
</script>
```

Comment: Why support IE6? Is there enough of a demand from IE6 users for your site that they need to be supported?

Comment: Cory, the js is supposed to draw cities and track on the map. This is not happening.

James, I upgraded to v8, and I am still having the problem.

Comment: If you are having the same problem on IE8 you can debug your javascript with the builtin developer tools (press F12 to open).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It wasn't in the code listed here. I had declared some variables as 'const' which IE doesn't recognize, and I was also using the for..in construct on arrays which I replaced with an indexed for loop. Everything fell in place once I discovered the js debugger in IE8. That sped things up tremendously! Now everything is looking good. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working with some js library, as i can see you dont, i sugest visit to site below and check your code there and fix those errors that are reported. That may give you some insight on whats going on.

http://jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Running your code through [jslint](http://jslint.com/), I got this warning

```
Problem at line 32 character 5: Bad for in variable 'key'.
```

Could be a DOM global variable or something. Change it and see what happens. Also, your `for..in` loop doesn't do what it is supposed to. It is for iterating though object properties, not through elements of an array. Use a plain for loop with an index.

Comment: The `for (key in cities)` works just fine.  I tested that in IE6.  Maybe how he's using `cities` them in `drawCities()` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, in this case, it may be working fine but in general, it is a bad idea. See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Chetan, thanks for pointing that out. I'm not as familiar with JS best practices as I should be. I will correct that.

Comment: `key` is an undeclared variable in this case, so when for-in is evaluated, `key` is declared as a global variable. That's not a good thing. Replace `for (key in cities)` with `for (var key in cities)` to fix it.